# Page content not updating after POST response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been attempting to create a simple page which updates after you have selected an `<option>` from a `<select>` tag.
So far I have been able to get a request going thru for my PHP script to receive the value of the selected option, but the response isn't affecting the displayed content (even though it really should). Firefox shows that the response is the entire page again, but with some additional text attached by the script so I know it went thru.

Even though I receive the response with the updated page/content, the page never seems to update.

index.php:

```
<?php
$pageName = "Index";
include "static/header.php";
require "static/db.php";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT id, year, make FROM public.vehs");
    $stmt->execute();
    $vals = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

#
#

$message = "";

if(isset($_POST['dropdownValue'])) {
    $message = "value set";
}
?>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select1').change(function(){
            //Selected value
            let inputValue = $(this).val();
            //Ajax for calling php function
            $.post('index.php', { dropdownValue: inputValue }, function(data){
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<select id="select1">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        <?php
            foreach($vals as $row) {
                echo("<option value='{$row["id"]}'>{$row["year"]} - {$row["make"]}</option>");
            }
        ?>
    </select><br>
<?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
    <p><?= $message ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</body>
```

header.php:

```
<?php
$pageName;
?>
<head>
    <title>Test Website - <?php echo $pageName ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/ajax.js"> # Really just jQuery, idk why i named it that
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

The request's response:

```
<head>
    <title>Test Website - Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/ajax.js"
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select1').change(function(){
            //Selected value
            let inputValue = $(this).val();
            //Ajax for calling php function
            $.post('index.php', { dropdownValue: inputValue }, function(data){
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<select id="select1">
        <option value="" disabled selected></option>
        <option value='1'>2020 - Test</option>    </select><br>
    <p>value set</p>
</body>
```

What I see in the browser after the request:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Test Website - Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/static/js/ajax.js" <script=""></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#select1').change(function(){
            //Selected value
            let inputValue = $(this).val();
            //Ajax for calling php function
            $.post('index.php', { dropdownValue: inputValue }, function(data){
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<select id="select1">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected=""></option>
        <option value="1">2020 - Test</option>    </select><br>

</body></html>
```

Comment: The `$.post` callback function needs to update the page as desired.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would that be done? I'm not very good at AJAX/jQuery

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: One thing to note is that an ajax response should not be returning a complete html document.  It should be returning a fragment, or only data that the script uses to generate a fragment.  If the response is returning a full page, perhaps you should use a normal form submit, rather than ajax.

Comment: Thanks, I guess.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, that will probably work out. I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do create another file like selected.php, because you are loading the whole HTML page while you only want to change the value inside p,  then after the data loaded you need to change the text inside `p` using $('p').text(data)

```
// selected.php
<?php
    $message = "";

    if(isset($_POST['dropdownValue'])) {
        $message = "value set";
    }
    echo $message;
?>
```

Edit your `index.php` file, to look like this

```
    .....
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#select1').change(function(){
                //Selected value
                let inputValue = $(this).val();
                //Ajax for calling php function
                $.post('selected.php', { dropdownValue: inputValue }, function(data){
                    $('p').text(data)
                });
            })
       });
    </script>
    ......
    <p>value not set</p>
```

Hope this will help!